# Rounded rectangular bottom border of text field using CSS

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

When we use `bottom-border` and then apply some `border-radius` on it, on a text field, we get 1st result as shown in the image below:

[image: Input field with border bottom]

But what if we want the `border-bottom` to be shown like a rounded rectangle as in case of 2nd field in the image? I'm looking for ideas specifically limited to css only. Though others are also invited to take part and think about it.

Comment: and what have you done so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element like `::before` or `::after` to mimic this border effect.

**Output Image:**

[image: Input field with rounded border bottom]

**Working Example:**

```css
.custom-input {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}

.custom-input::before {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: black;
  height: 6px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.custom-input input {
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-input">
  <input type="text" value="This is a text field width bottom border" />
</div>
```

---

Alternatively you can use `linear-gradient()` and `radial-gradient()` to create 3 different images and draw on appropriate positions to create similar effect.

Here is necessary CSS:

```
input {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, black 3px, transparent 3px),
                      linear-gradient(to right, black, black),
                      radial-gradient(circle, black 3px, transparent 3px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 6px 6px, calc(100% - 8px) 6px, 6px 6px;
    background-position: left bottom, center bottom, right bottom;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.custom-input {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, black 3px, transparent 3px),
                       linear-gradient(to right, black, black),
                       radial-gradient(circle, black 3px, transparent 3px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 6px 6px, calc(100% - 8px) 6px, 6px 6px;
    background-position: left bottom, center bottom, right bottom;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 360px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="custom-input" value="This is a text field width bottom border" />
```

Comment: Oh, instead of adding the border directly to the input field you did it to the div containing it. But we won't be able to do this directly on the text field.

Comment: @NishcheyInderesh There was no such constraint mentioned in your question. You should describe complete scenario in your question.

Comment: No, I wasn't saying that you didn't answer my question, you did it indeed very well... I'm sorry for offending you, that I didn't surely meant to. It was just an expression that I won't be able to apply it on the text-field directly. Though you helped me start at least. Thanks for your answer. I'll think further to apply it directly to the text field. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NishcheyInderesh if you won't be able to apply this solution why not simply make your question more clear and add the necessary code ? then we will be able to help you ... and if this answer is not what you are looking for exactly why accepting it (nothing against you Mohammad !), By doing this you remove it from the unanswered question queue and you will no more get help as it's considered as solved.

Comment: @NishcheyInderesh No, I'm not offended. But you should describe complete details regarding your question. However I've added another variant that allows you to create border like effect directly on input field in case you can't make changes in HTML.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Actually I just needed a start and Mohammad Usman guided me very well. I didn't say that this answer didn't help me. It did. I will just further modify it according to my needs or think over it a bit more to come up with a solution that can be directly applied to the text field border attribute. And also you asked me about my code. Sometimes, we just need a start and have the potential to take it further. Did something like this never happen to you when you were learning. Thanks for trying to help though. Have a nice day.

Comment: wow @MohammadUsman You're awesome. Thank you so much and next time, I'll remember to add all the details. Sorry for now, it was my first time. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @NishcheyInderesh sorry to say that but here we don't do such thing ... you need to notice that here it's not a Forum but Q/A site. The main purpose is that you have tried something and you failed somewhere so you come here with your fail and we try to guide you in order to fix it. But if you come with such a question which is too broad this will lead to more suggestions/discussions than bug fixing, As we can provide you with many more ways than Mohammad already done

Comment: Yes @TemaniAfif I agree and I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

HTML element's `::after` will work.

```css
h1 {
    position: relative;
    width:380px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
h1::after {
    content: "";
    border: 4px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>Your Text Here..</h1>
```